# How to update a single instance of a widget in android

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to update a single instance of a widget (not all the widgets) from an activity. If I click on my widget I will go to an activity . From there I can set the property of the widget (e.g.: the background color). what I want is that, I need to update the property of the widget in which I clicked. Not for all the widgets.
The function is shown below:

```
public void set(View view)
{
    final Context context = ColorPick.this;
     RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget_layout);
     views.setTextColor(R.id.ap, Color.rgb(r, g, b));
     ComponentName thiswidget = new ComponentName(context,TimeWidgetProvider.class);
    AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
     manager.updateAppWidget(thiswidget, views);
}
```